# About Module Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $k$ be a subring of the center of ring $R$.

How to show that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is a $k$-module in a canonical way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would be helpful if you included some context. How did you come across this question? What have you tried in terms of answering it? It is a good idea to include context so that people can help you get the best answer for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ and $a\in k$, define
$$
af\colon M\to N,\qquad af\colon x\mapsto f(ax)=af(x)
$$
It's just a matter of standard verifications to show that $af\in\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ and that this group has, in this way, the structure of $k$-module.

Be sure to point out where the property that $k$ is a subset of the center is used.

Comment: Since we are assuming ring is not commutative Hom(M,N) may not be R-module but since elements in center commutes with all other we can prove that it is k-module right?

Comment: @DineshMohite That's the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help